# hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: InventoryItems of: com.example.demo.model.PurchaseOrder

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting Query Exception while fetching purchase order list.
hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: InventoryItems of: com.example.demo.model.PurchaseOrder

Entity Inventory

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory")
public class Inventory {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String name;
private String unit_of_measurement;
private float unit_cost;
private int opening_balance;
private float dim_length;
private float dim_breadth;
private float dim_height;
}
```

Entity Purchase

```
enter code here
@Entity
@Table(name="purchase_order")
public class PurchaseOrder {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long purchase_order_number;
private String vendor_name;
private Date purchase_order_date;
private float tax;

@Column(name = "total_cost", columnDefinition ="real default 0")
private double total_cost;
@Column(name ="net_cost", columnDefinition = " real default 0")
private double net_cost;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchaseOrder",orphanRemoval = 
           true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY   )
private List<InventoryItems> inventoryItems;
}
```

Entity Inventory Items

```
enter code here

@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_items")
public class InventoryItems {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long inventory_items;

private int quantity;

private double cost;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable = false)
private Inventory inventory;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="purchase_order_number",insertable=true, 
updatable=true, nullable = false)
private PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;
}
```

I am trying to write this Query , but it is throwing an exception.

```
@Query("select po from PurchaseOrder as po  join po.InventoryItems as 
i where i.id=?1 ")
List<PurchaseOrder> findPurchaseOrderByItem(long id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In purchase entity you have declared field inventoryitems with a lower case 'i'
private List inventoryItems

Whereas while writing query you have used po.InventoryItems

Try using po.inventoryItems instead.

Comment: Glad to help :)